# Determining if byte and vec3_t typedef'd

Tags: c, byte, c-preprocessor, c11, preprocessor-directive

C11 has some things as part of the spec like byte and vec3_t.

Is there a way to determine via an `#ifdef` if those are already defined as too support as many compilers as possible without warnings?

Comment: Do you have any reference for this: *C11 has some things as part of the spec like byte and vec3_t.* ?

Comment: Clang is throwing me those compiler warnings ( warning: redefinition of typedef 'byte' is a C11 feature [-Wtypedef-redefinition] )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the error message. These types are not defined by C11, but it seems that they are already defined in your include files somewhere else. What the message is refering to is that since C11 `typedef`s can be re-iterated, if they refer to the same type. This is made so to have the same behavior as for variable or function declarations or `#define`. All these can appear several times, as long as they are consistent.

To have that feature, you should compile with option `-std=c11` or `-std=gnu11`. This should make the message disappear.

In your case, the message probably shows that you have some error in your include logic, so it is probably a better idea to get that straight.